# full text search indexeddb, example implementations

Tags: full-text-search, indexeddb

i'm quite aware that it's not described in the spec, but if i can obtain a keyword array from my back end for my, say 'article' object, how would i search against it with a given search phrase?

i'm coming from ruby on rails, if that'd help to explain

---

a prominent example floating around the webs is a to-do list example, and another one
(see: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/uidatabinding/ NOTE: broken for chrome)
lets imagine the primary model in each case, (todo task, and employee) to have an associated array of keywords in addition to what's described in the articles.

Now say i wanted to get the task that mentions 'roman history' based on keywords (or 'clerical work' for the employee example) stored in the respective aforementioned array.

How in the h*** would you do this?

---

Note: I'd be using this to build a google chrome packaged app and a phonegap app with either sencha touch 2 or backbone.js (if one or the either would make the above easier, do tell)

Comment: can we re-open this question? or link to related questions? (it's 2020, and afaict from MDN, the IndexedDB specification/implementations have changed.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am planing to implement very simple full-text search in [YDN-DB](https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db). I am thinking as follow:

1. Annotate the schema with *full-text* for an index of an object store, which effectively  create *keyword reference table*. *keyword reference table* is one-to-many relationship table to keyPath of the parent object store. The relationship data type is array, i think it is more efficient than multiple entry of references.
2. When putting the object, split keywords from the value of the index and update the *keyword reference table* referencing keyPath of the object store.
3. To query a full text search, open key cursor to *keyword reference table* giving a range of the search terms. The range will pull out all keyword start with the given search terms. From the result corresponding full record are take from the parent object store. The search is performed in single transaction.

Later key cursor can expand to include related phase.

The implementation is very straight forward and retrieval should be very fast.

EDIT:

Implemented in [YDN-DB-FULLTEXT](https://github.com/yathit/ydn-db-fulltext) repo.

### Features

- Unicode-base tokenization supporting full language spectrum.
- Stemming and phonetic normalization for English language.
- Free text query base ranking with logical and, or and near.
- Support exact match and prefix match.
- Being based on YDN-DB, storage mechanisms could be IndexedDB, WebSQL or localStorage.
- Easy and flexible configuration using fulltext catalog.

### API Reference

Use `search` method to query full text search.

```
db.search(catalog, query)
```

Documents are indexed during storing into the database using add or put methods.

Query format is free text, in which implicit and/or/near logic operator apply
for each token. Use double quote for exact match, - to subtract from the result
and * for prefix search.

*Parameters:*

- `{string} catalog`
  Full text search catalog name, as defined in schema.
- `{string} query`
  Free text query string.

*Returns:*

`{!ydn.db.Request}` Returns a request object.

`done: {Array}` Return list of inverted index. An inverted index has the
  following attributes: `storeName`, `primaryKey`, `score`, `tokens`, representing for
  store name of original document, primary key of original document, match
  quality score and array of token objects. Token object has the following
  attributes: `keyPath`, `value` and `loc` representing key path of index of the
  original document, original word from the original document and array list of
  position of word in the document.

`fail: {Error}` If any one of deleting a key fail, fail callback is invoked,
  with the resulting error in respective elements.

`progress: {Array}` During index retrieval, raw inverted index are dispatched.

### Example

```
var schema = {
  fullTextCatalogs: [{
    name: 'name',
    lang: 'en',
      sources: [
        {
          storeName: 'contact',
          keyPath: 'first'
        }],
    ]},
    stores: [
      {
        name: 'contact',
        autoIncrement: true
      }]
};
var db = new ydn.db.Storage('db name', schema);
db.put('contact', [{first: 'Jhon'}, {first: 'Collin'}]);
db.search('name', 'jon').done(function(x) {
  console.log(x);
  db.get(x[0].storeName, x[0].primaryKey).done(function(top) {
    console.log(top);
  })
});
```

### Full text catalog

Full text catalog is a logical grouping of one or more full-text indexes. It is
defined in database initialization in database schema.

*Fields:*

- `{string} name` Full text catalog name.
- `{string=} lang` Language. Stemming, word segmentation and phonetic normalization
  are language dependent. `lang` must be defined to index properly. Currently
  only `en` is well supported. For more languages, check out on [natural](https://github.com/yathit/natural.git)
  project repo.
- `{Array} indexes` Full text indexes. Each index has source reference to
  original document by `storeName` and `keyPath`. The value of `keyPath` is
  the text to be indexed. `weight` factor is applied when ranking search result.
  This value is not stored in the database can be changed after indexing as well.

The following full text catalog index author name on `first` and `last` field
of record value with weighting more on `first`.

```
var catalog = {
  name: 'author-name',
  lang: 'en',
  sources: [{
    storeName: 'author',
    keyPath: 'first',
    weight: 1.0
  }, {
    storeName: 'author',
    keyPath: 'last',
    weight: 0.8
}]
```

### Demo applications

- [Animal database search](http://dev.yathit.com/demo/ydn-db-text/animals/animals.html)
  Basic indexing operation, featuring text suggestion input.
- [Biomedical Medical Journal Abstract Search](http://dev.yathit.com/demo/ydn-db-text/pubmed-search/index.html)
  Ajax data load, free text search ranking and presenting result with matching words highlighted.
- [All demos](http://dev.yathit.com/index/demos.html)

Comment: That sounds excellent! I can see how I'd implement 1 and 2 but I'm unfamiliar with indexeddb and I'm not sure of the query syntax for a range of search terms.

Comment: The Firefox website has what sounds like a close example:     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB#Using_an_index     //Match anything between "Bill" and "Donna", but not including "Donna"
var boundKeyRange = IDBKeyRange.bound("Bill", "Donna", false, true);

Comment: Yes, that is. For example opening IDBKeyRange.bound('bill', 'bill\uffff'), will include all terms starting bill. As you see, indexing only lower case, so only case-insensitive can be performed.

Comment: what about in the following case: i want every keyword that contains the word "users", i have two keywords, "users" and "smartphone users", would that query do what i want?

Comment: yes, it will. for two keywords search, two IDBKeyRange cursers ("smartphone" and "users") will be opened in a transaction. a ranking scheme should result higher ranking for "smartsphone users" over just "users" or it could be specified to meet both keywords.

Comment: BTW, "smartphone" will not come up when searching for "phone" as keyword. Indexing is just scanning on sorted array. It is very simple.

Comment: that's unfortunate, could i use regular expressions to enable searches with the keyword "phone" to also bring up the "smartphone" keyword?

Comment: yes, that is unfortunate. indexing do not work that way. no regular expression. just scanning on sorted array. perhaps you could split "smartphone" to "smart" and "phone" before indexing. then it will work.

Comment: is there an alternate way to do search if i'm willing to take a hit on speed for the sake of accuracy?

Comment: the last resort is opening the whole object store and iterate each record at a time. you can start from any point. in each iteration, you can perform all your wild algorithms, including regexp to the current record. then you decide to continue to next iteration or jump specific key or just exist if you found what you are looking for. this technique don't need indexing.

Comment: another way is, you can do more indexing. for example you can index triplet, like 'aaa', 'aab', 'aac', or syllable. so it is balancing between storage space and cpu time.

Comment: would doing iteration + regex against the keyword table be faster than iterating + regex directly against the article table?

Comment: on the other hand, using WebDB (WebSQL) or some other DB that has a LIKE operator or something similar is an option, even though WebSQL is depricated, technically.

Comment: Maybe take a look at my indexeddb framework:  http://linq2indexeddb.codeplex.com In this framework I provide a like functionality. This is not done by using indexes, but executing the filter directly on the data in a web worker.

Comment: yeah, if you are doing regexp, better go with directly to article table.

Comment: sorry, @KristofDegrave this is going to be a phonegap app, primarily used offline